# C# разработка GUI

Tags: c#, canvas, gui

Подскажите пожалуйста, на каком фреймворке C# в данный момент актуально создавать GUI?

По потребностям: нужно создать карту помещения и визуально удобно расположить на ней оборудование, чтобы это скролилось, перемещалось; запускать под windows 7/8/10

При беглом гуглении я понял, что есть WPF, AvaloniaUI и Xamarin.Forms. Но тому кто с ними не знаком - сложно вообще понять чем они отличаются, какие плюсы и недостатки.

п.с. Я сам с Unity работаю, и там достаточно удобно создавать интерфейсы, а здесь заминка вышла на данном этапе

Comment: Так и делайте на Unity 3D, раз у вас там карта, оборудование... разве Unity не для этого как-раз? )

Answer (score 3):

Если виндоус онли - WPF

Хочется еще линукс - Авалония, но можно и на ней чисто под винду. В принципе пойдет все равно

Под мобилки - Замарин.

Можете и на юнити, почему нет?)